# use net instread of cdrom. linux, aptitude install

Tags: sudo, system-installation

Got debian installed [finally](https://superuser.com/questions/613885/install-debian-stable-linux-iso-from-usb-to-dual-boot-windows/614363#614363) but during install I think I choose to use the local media over the internet for packages. needed to do that as was not sure if will try to connect right away (my modem needs a login).

Now I want to install/ enable sudo and install other programs like thunderbird eclipse, and chrome. but I do not have sudo

when I type the command,

```
aptitude install sudo
```

Get this message:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  sudo  0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not
upgraded. Need to get 0 B/842 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,882 kB
will be used. Media change: Please insert the disc labeled 'Debian
GNU/Linux 7.1.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 CD Binary-1 20130615-23:06'
into the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter].
```

Do not have a cdrom. What to do? Have root user password though logged in as another user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to root, you can edit the /etc/apt/sources.list file as described on the debian site [here](http://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList)
use 
su
enter root password

then with an editor (nano is easy to use as it has menus if you have it installed otherwise vi is most likely to be present, see a manual for vi [here](http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/text_editing/vim.html) )

nano /etc/apt/sources.list
or 
vi /etc/apt/sources.list